# I'm trying to make three dice roll and have their output show, but I am having trouble trying to figure it out.

Tags: java

I am trying to make my program be able to show the count of how many times it takes until 3 dice land on the same number and then tell the use how many times it took, the number that it had landed on and have them repeat this process 3 times. However, I can't figure out how to make the program work. Currently, only Try, Dice 1, Dice 2, Dice 3 pop up, and then the amount of rolls it took under Try. How do I make the rest of this program work? Thanks!

```
import java.util.Random;
public class Q1
  {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random g=new Random();
    boolean same=false;
    int dice1=0;
    int dice2=0;
    int dice3=0;
    int count=0;
    System.out.println("Try\tDice 1\tDice 2\tDice 3");
    do{
            System.out.println();
            count++;
            dice1=g.nextInt(6)+1;
            dice2=g.nextInt(6)+1;
            dice3=g.nextInt(6)+1;
            System.out.print(count+"\t");

            if(dice1==dice2 && dice2==dice3){
            same=true;
            System.out.println("It took"+count+"times and they all landed on number "+??);
           }
       }
       while(!same);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a counter to count only when you get your match.  That way you are counting only the number of times it has matched.
For while, change the condition to while < 3.
For the print, you can add dice1 to the end of that System.out.println

```
int count=0;
int matchCount = 0;
System.out.println("Try\tDice 1\tDice 2\tDice 3");
do{
        System.out.println();
        count++;
        dice1=g.nextInt(6)+1;
        dice2=g.nextInt(6)+1;
        dice3=g.nextInt(6)+1;
        System.out.print(count+"\t");

        if(dice1==dice2 && dice2==dice3){
        same=true;
        matchCount++;
        System.out.println("It took"+count+"times and they all landed on number "+dice1);
       }
   }
   while(matchCount < 3);
```